# Ambiguous use of "value" while implementing UIStepper

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode6.3

I am trying to implement a simple stepper which reflects its value onto a label.
While using "Int(sender.value)" I am getting an error "Ambiguous use of value"

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  Stepper
//
//  Created by Prabhu Konchada on 19/06/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Prabhu. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var StepperValue: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var OutputLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func StepperTap(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.OutputLabel.text = String(Int(sender.value).description)
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are converting the value to Int ?

Comment: @AshishKakkad I tired without it which successfully builds but throws this error  0x1947e2a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) . So I followed this tutorial http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/uistepper-tutorial-ios8-swift

Comment: @AshishKakkad I think the problem was using AnyObject instead of sender :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like as follows :

```
@IBOutlet var lblStep: UILabel!
@IBAction func stepPressed(sender: UIStepper) {

    lblStep.text = sender.value.description

}
```

else you have to convert `AnyObject` to `UIStepper`
like as

```
var stepControl : UIStepper = sender as! UIStepper
```

as like :

```
@IBAction func StepperTap(sender: AnyObject) {
    var stepControl : UIStepper = sender as! UIStepper
    self.OutputLabel.text = stepControl.value.description
}
```

Whole code as version 6.1 you have to just change to as with as! for 6.3.2:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var lblStep: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func stepPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        var step : UIStepper = sender as UIStepper

        lblStep.text = step.value.description

    }
}
```

Comment: 2015-06-20 10:57:00.261 Stepper[19697:2335171] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Stepper.ViewController 0x12f512e40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Action.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1829902d8 0x1941640e4 0x18298ff5c 0x1837c9480 0x1828bb520 0x1877f07a0 0x1876ec384 0x1873d0a28 0x1873d0994 0x1873d71d0 0x1873d4880 0x180d9cd24 0x1874468ec 0x18765aa94 0x18765d208 0x18765b778 0x18b1a13c8 0x18294827c )
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: The Second : AnyObject cannot be converted to UIStepper

Comment: I too have checked it can you upload the file ??

Comment: Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)

Comment: Tried it Didn't work : 2015-06-20 11:05:14.295 Stepper[19725:2337567] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Stepper.ViewController 0x14d612840> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:

Comment: @Ashsih Kakkad Probably something wrong with my project file worked on another one I am deleting this question Sorry My Bad :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your code like this:

```
@IBAction func StepperTap(sender: UIStepper) {

    self.OutputLabel.text = "\(sender.value)"
}
```

Comment: It throws an error saying : Could not find member 'init' ; Anyway may I Know what  does '\' do ??

Comment: The main issue here is the type of the `sender` variable. When you created the IBAction, you did not select UIStepper, but AnyObject. The \\(sender.value) is called string interpolation - it inserts value of sender.value into a string. using sender.value.description will do the same thing.